# Styling table to fill remaining space and scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a css layout.

I'm trying to do the layout without resorting to javascript to position elements.

The overall layout is fine, barring the problem with table filling the remaining space

```
=============================
| LT |  TOP            | TR |
=============================
|  Variable height section  |
|                           |
=============================
| Title                     |
|===========================|
| TABLE to fill remaining   |
| with scrollable body and  |
| scrollable table (i.e.    |
| fixed headers)            |
=============================
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/44cbf4L5/2/

Can anyone suggest a way of making the table fill it's parent div.

thanks in advance.

#### EDIT 1

Thanks for comments, this fiddle is closer http://jsfiddle.net/44cbf4L5/11/ although the 100% height and width doesn't account for the width of the scroll bars.

I suppose the next part of the question is how to you size to 100% height or width including height of width of scroll bars?  almost like a box-sizing attrib for scrollbars?

Comment: set height:100%; on the datatable class?

Comment: it doesn't work properly when using a block element.  Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/44cbf4L5/7/  with 100% width and height and what would you set tbody's height too?

Comment: @sambomartin - why do you need to set `display:block` there? Isn't this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/44cbf4L5/9/

Comment: kind of, the height is right, but want to scroll the table independently of the page. Likewise with the table body. Table body should be vert scrolling (i.e. fixed header) and table (inc headers) horz scrolling. I don't want the document (browser) scroll bars visible (needed)

Answer (score 0):

Change the width on table from 500px to 100%

Comment: it doesn't work properly when using a block element.  Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/44cbf4L5/7/  with 100% width and height and what would you set tbody's height too?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this if I understand correctly ?

```
table.datatable{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work properly when using a block element.  Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/44cbf4L5/7/  with 100% width and height and what would you set tbody's height too?

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed width of `datatable`.

Update this css:

```
table.datatable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
    background:white;
    /* here i want the table to fill the (width - width of scroll bar) */
    /*width:500px;--------------------here it should be removed*/
    /* and height 100% */
    /* height:100%; */
}
```

## [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44cbf4L5/6/)

Comment: thanks manwal, but the table is extending over document causing scollbars on body.  i need to set width in order to clip the content of table and use the scoll bar of table

Comment: No i think you are confuse with jsfiddle. See full screen it is perfect http://jsfiddle.net/44cbf4L5/6/embedded/result/

Comment: the height of the table i'm trying to fill the space height and width and I want to scroll the table body vertically and the table horizontally. I dont want to use/see the browser (document) scroll bars

Comment: it's closer, but want table to fill the space remaining and the tbody to be vert scrollable and the overall table to be horz scrollable. in your fiddle the theader scroll out of view and the width and height of table is still an absolute value.